# Angular checkout payment

Tags: angular, realex-payments-api

I'm new here, thanks in advance

I wanted to ask what is the process to make a payment through a payment gateway in Angular 5, I have seen that there is a stripe but it costs money.

I have made a POST call from a javascript form but in the response of the gateway I can not get the data (error 405).

What would be the ideal way to make a payment? Could you help me?

thank you very much

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate a little bit? The 405 error occurs when a client web does a request with a wrong http method (POST,GET,PUT). Did you check payment gateway api?. See you.

Comment: Thank you,

I am making a call to a payment gateway of the realex-payment-api type but I am requested to make the payment through a standard javascript form by POST, I have created this form so that I can make the call without Angular by adding "form ngNoForm" and it works well .

But the response of the payment gateway redirects to an url of my Angular page also through POST to send the payment data and from the bank they tell us that it gives a 405 response.

I would like to know how I can accept the POST entry of the bank's answer on a page.

Comment: This is my form of sending data to the bank:
<form ngNoForm #extForm action="https://hpp.prueba.santanderelavontpvvirtual.es/pay" method="POST">
    <button type="button" (click)="proceedToService(extForm)">External 
       Service</button>
    </form>

And this is the answer they are having in the bank once the payment is finalized correctly and they try to call my page:

Comment: 2018-01-29 17:34:07.550 Http Status Code:405 
2018-01-29 17:34:07.550 Detail error message from apache http client :Method Not Allowed 
2018-01-29 17:34:07.550 Retry attempts :3 
2018-01-29 17:34:07.553 Fail to send response to merchant 
2018-01-29 17:34:07.557 Following error occurred during processing of request. 
2018-01-29 17:34:07.557 Fail to send response to merchant